# Do we have a way to change the colors of the polygons directly in JOSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, polygon, josm

Do we have a way to change directly the colors of the polygons in JOSM?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the appearance in JOSM via [styles](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Styles). There are already [various different styles available](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Styles#Availablestyleslist). Alternatively you can [create your own style](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Styles#CreateStyle).

This affects only the map rendering in JOSM of course.